# Succession Limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Thru the limit definition $(u_n)$ is the succession and $a$ is the limit of it :

$$
\left(u_n\right)\to\:a\:\:\Longleftrightarrow:\forall ε>0\:\:\:\exists p:\:\:\:\forall n\::\:\:\left(n>p\:\:\Rightarrow\:\left|u_n-a\right|< \:ε\right)
$$

I need to prove the following:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\rightarrow 0
$$

- **Zero** is my **'a'**, (to where the Succession is going) and $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ $$  is my '$\mathbf {u_n}$'

I don't even know from where should I start.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Suppose Mr. Opponent throws an $\varepsilon$ at you. How do you react?

Comment: Say sequence, not succession.

Comment: @Unit I don't know

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you!: )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For any $\varepsilon >0$ we need to find a $p$ such that if $n>p$ then $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}<\varepsilon$

reverse the inequality

$\sqrt{n+1}>\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\to n+1>\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\to n>\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}-1$

So if we take $p=\lceil \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}-1\rceil$, for any $n>p$ it happens that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}<\varepsilon$

For instance take $\varepsilon =10^{-6}$ we take $p=\lceil 10^{12} -1\rceil$ so if $n>p$ for instance if $n=10^{14}-1$ it happens that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10^{14}}}=10^{-7}<10^{-6}$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for helping! :)